# How to get all Phone Storage(internal storage) directory list

Tags: android

I want to get all files list of internal storage. I've write this code,

```
File dir= getFilesDir();
        File[] list = dir.listFiles();
        for(File ff: list) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ff.getName() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

it just gives me **Directory name: instant-run** on Toast but my internal storage has many direcoties as you can see below picture, 
[image]

kindly tell me how to get all these directories name.

Comment: they cannot resolve my issue. I want to get list of internal storage not external storage.

Comment: `/Home/Phone storage/` is not a valid path for an Android device. Better use a decent file explorer app. This one should be avoided and its programmer(s) fired.

Comment: then how i can distinguish internal storage and external storage (SD card) in our app

Comment: Your question is wrong. And new as there is internal storage AND external storage AND sd card. Three. Please stay with your original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to list all the directory in internal storage. please try this, it work's fine for me as i am using only internal storage in my phone.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.sumesh.filendirectory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileNDirectoryActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> fileList=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        ListDir(root);
    }

    void ListDir(File f){
        File[] files=f.listFiles();
        fileList.clear();
        for (File file: files){
            fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fileList);
        setListAdapter(directoryList);
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sumesh.filendirectory">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".FileNDirectoryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
```

hope it helps.
if you are using android version 6 or above, once you install the app it will crash for sure because of storage run-time permission now how to resolve? add run-time permission code for storage and if you are lazy follow this one.

- goto ==> installed app ==> app info screen
- on permission list item give storage permission then it will run smoothly.

[image]

**Other ways to do so:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lview1);
        String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File f = new File(path);//converted string object to file
        String[] values = f.list();//getting the list of files in string array
        //now presenting the data into screen
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, values);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter

    }
}
```

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lview1">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sumesh.listview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is of what the Android SDK calls [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). The root of external storage is obtained via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: i know about getExternalStorageDirectory() but i want to get internal storage directories. How can i get?

Comment: @Zohaib: Let me try boldface: **your screenshot is of what the Android SDK calls external storage, not internal storage**. If you want to reproduce what is in the screenshot, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. You cannot "get all these directories name" using `getFilesDir()`, because "all these directories" are on external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare as of API 29 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated. Is there any other approach?

Comment: @MADLAD: On Android 10, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 29 or higher, you will not be able to read content on external storage, except in a few limited places. On Android 11, you get that access back, but this method remains deprecated. Instead, you can use `StorageManager` to find a `StorageVolume`, then call [`getDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume?#getDirectory()) on that. AFAIK, that's the long-term replacement for `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get dirs using below code...

```
File extStorageDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    String fileList=extStorageDir.list();

    for(String fileName:fileList)
    sysout("FileName="+fileNAme);
```

Comment: i know about getExternalStorageDirectory() but i want to get internal storage directories. How can i get?

Comment: you can use String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();