# Fragment and file viewer

Tags: android, android-fragments, media

I want to make an app to show all type file in 4 fragments(image, videos, music, application) .

What is the basic solution to storing the list of photos, videos, programs and music for work in the fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For files present in internal or external storage like images, videos and audio files you can get a reference to them and store them in File class object. For full tutorial :https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080091/10602679  and
https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listing-all-sdcard-filenames-with-extensions-in-android

For getting the list of all installed applications, you will need to query the PackageManager class and get list of all applications using ResolverInfo object. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696617/10602679